# ADFS - Authentication only, no claims. Android App

Tags: android, oauth, adfs, ws-federation

At our company we have an **ADFS 3.0** proxy infrastructure facing internet. We already have made some straightforward integrations (Salesforce, Custom Apps, ...)

This time a software partner is building an **Android** app for us. The scenario is as follows:
 - The app is a rich app, an apk
 - The app is running in tablets outside our network, they will have 3G cards to access the internet.
 - The app needs to authenticate corporate AD users with their corporate passwords.
 - The app will login and logout different users several times a day. The device is not assigned to a person.
 - The devices/app are not enroled in our domain

Since we have ADFS 3.0 reachable from the apk, we are going to use it to authenticate users, it seems that OAuth is our best bet, and that we could also use WS-Federation.

1. Do you thin OAuth and WS-Fed fit this scenario?
2. Does ADFS bring some service that we can use to autenticate the user?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer: Use WS-Trust.

We can expose WS-Trust with ADFS at https://our.adfs.server/adfs/services/trust/13/UsernameMixed

From our code we create a request security token using UsernameToken encrypted with the server cert.

All parameters been OK, we receive the SAML assertion as a response.